# How to use (custom) Geographic Types of MemSQL using Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, singlestore

I am currently trying to use Slick to use MemSQL. MemSQL is based on SQL syntax and handles geospatial types :https://docs.memsql.com/docs/geospatial-guide

I am trying to use a custom type to have an easy way to use slick :

```
package entities

import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

sealed case class GeographicPoint(valuec: String) {
  var value: String = valuec
  implicit val colType = MappedColumnType.base[GeographicPoint, String] (
    {_.value},
    {GeographicPoint(_)}
  )
}

class AreaNodes(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, GeographicPoint)](tag, "AREA_NODES"){
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def centroid = column[GeographicPoint] ("CENTROID")
  def * = (id, name, centroid)
}
```

At compilation time, i have the following error :

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[entities.GeographicPoint]
```